# Will any 10 speed cassette work with a 10 speed shifter?

Tags: cassette, shifter

I have a 10 speed shifter Shimano Deore SL-M610. I replaced the cassette from Shimano CS-HG50, 11-36 to XT M771 10, 11-36 about a yer ago. I'm currently experiencing some issues with the chain slipping off the cassette. I'm pretty sure I need to replace the chain and chainset, but just wanted to check if the new cassette could have caused incompatibility and issues with chain slippage?

Really appreciate your time and help with this.

Rob

Comment: With chain slippage, do you mean it’s not staying in the selected gear or that it’s actually slipping when you pedal hard? I’ve only ever heard of this on fixed gear bicycles with insufficient chain tension. If it’s not staying in the gear it’s probably just an adjustment issue, cable friction or a bent derailleur hanger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shimano and SRAM cassettes of the same speeds (up to 11 speed) are all basically compatible with each other. The overall cassette width and individual sprocket widths and spacings are standardized for each number of speeds.

(This does not mean you can use any 10 size speed cassette in a drivetrain of course, as the derailleur has to be able to handle the cassette sprocket size range.)

Because sprocket widths and spacings are standardized, all shifter/derailleur combinations for a given number of speeds move the derailleur cage the same amount per click, to match with the cassette sprocket spacings. The amount of cable pulled by the shifter per click differs between Shimano and SRAM but this is compensated for by the derailleur actuation ratio.

If your chain is coming off the innermost or outermost sprockets you need to [adjust the derailleur limits](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment). If the chain is overriding the sprockets under hard pedaling check chain and cassette sprocket wear. Note that a worn chain accelerates wear on cassettes and chainrings. I recommend getting a chain wear gauge as they are cheap and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please could you clarify what you mean by the cassette range? - is this the spacing between each ring on the cassette?

Comment: Cassette range is the size difference between smallest and largest sprockets. The derailleur has to be able to take up the chain slack difference between largest chainring-largest sprocket and smallest-smallest (known as total capacity), and also needs to be able to accommodate the largest sprocket.

Comment: Thanks again. So to confirm, does that mean the shifter, in this case Shimano Deore SL-M610, cause no compatibility issues with a cassette? - In other words as long as it's there's a 10 speed shift connected to a 10 speed rear derailleur, the only compatibility issue is between the derailleur and the rear cassette?

Comment: Yes, if you have a Shimano 10 speed MTB shifter and derailleur and 10 speed cassette it should all work together.